# Dynamic links with angularjs and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-ng-repeat, dynamic-linking

I'm creating an app using fake [JSONplaceholder API](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com,2). I'm displaying a list of posts and I want the ng-repeated post titles to link to the post view.

Here's the HTML:

```
    <body layout="column" ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak ng-controller="controller">
    <h1>{{apptitle}}</h1>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="allposts.htm">
        <a href="#addpost">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addbtn" ng-model="singleModel" uib-btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0">
        Add a post
    </button>
</a>
        View
        <select ng-model="viewby" ng-change="setItemsPerPage(viewby)">
            <option>9</option>
            <option>18</option>
            <option>36</option>
            <option>100</option>
        </select>posts
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="collatedPostList in collatedPosts">
            <div class="onepost col-xs-4 box" ng-repeat="post in collatedPostList">
                 <div class="inner">
                <a href="#/posts/{{post.indexOf(post)}}">{{post.title}}</a>
                <p>{{post.body | limitTo: 60}}{{post.body.length < 20 ? '' : '...'}}</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
        <ul uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" class="pagination-sm"
            items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-change="pageChanged(currentPage)"></ul>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="posts.htm">
  </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="addpost.htm">
    <form ng-submit="addPost()" class="adding">
        <input id="titleadd" type="text" name="title" ng-model="newPost.title" placeholder="Add title">
        <br>
        <input id="textadd" type="text" name="body" ng-model="newPost.body" placeholder="Add some text">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="addAlert(msg,'success')" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="Submit">
        Post it
        </button>
        <a href="#allposts">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
            Go back to post list
        </button></a>
            <br>
        <uib-alert 
              ng-repeat="alert in alerts" 
              type="{{alert.type}}" 
              dismiss-on-timeout="5000" 
              close="alerts.splice($index, 1);">{{alert.msg}}
    </uib-alert>    </form>
  </script>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

and JS:

```
Array.prototype.collate = function(collateSize) {
    var collatedList = [];

    if (collateSize <= 0) {
        return [];
    }
    angular.forEach(this, function(item, index) {
        if (index % collateSize === 0) {
            collatedList[Math.floor(index / collateSize)] = [item];
        } else {
            collatedList[Math.floor(index / collateSize)].push(item);
        }
    });

    return collatedList;
};

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'allposts.htm',
        controller: 'PostsController'
    }).when('/posts', {
        templateUrl: 'posts.htm',
        controller: 'PostController'
    }).when('/addpost', {
        templateUrl: 'addpost.htm',
        controller: 'AddController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

myApp.controller('PostsController', function($scope) {});

myApp.controller('PostController', function($scope) {});

myApp.controller('AddController', function($scope) {});


myApp.controller('controller', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.apptitle = "My app";

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.posts = response.data;
        $scope.viewby = 9;
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.posts.length;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewby;
        $scope.maxSize = 5;
        $scope.collatedPosts = getCollatedPosts($scope.posts);
        $scope.newPost = {};


    function getCollatedPosts(posts) {
        if (!posts) {
            return [];
        }

        var paginatedPosts = posts.slice((($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage), (($scope.currentPage) * $scope.itemsPerPage));
        return paginatedPosts.collate(3);
    }

    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };

    $scope.setItemsPerPage = function(num) {
        $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //reset to first page
        $scope.collatedPosts = getCollatedPosts($scope.posts);
    };

    $scope.pageChanged = function(currentPage) {
        $scope.currentPage = currentPage;
        $scope.collatedPosts = getCollatedPosts($scope.posts);
    };
        $scope.addPost = function(){
          $http.post("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",{
            title: $scope.newPost.title,
            body: $scope.newPost.body,
            usrId: 1
          })
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost);
            $scope.newPost = {};
          })
          .error(function(error, status, headers, config){
            console.log(error);
          });
    };});


    $scope.alerts = [];

    $scope.msg = "Well done! Your post was added";

    $scope.addAlert = function(msg, type) {
      $scope.alerts.push({
        msg: msg,
        type: type
      });
    };

});
```

My code is not working. There is 100 ng-repeated posts and I want each post title to link to the post view. Current code links every title to `#/posts`. I also tried `<a href="#/posts/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a>`, but with no success.
What is the correct way to do this?

You can see full code [here](http://codepen.io/summerfreeze/pen/ORVQYz):

Comment: Should that be <a href="#!/posts/{{post.id}}"> - it looks like you left out the exclamation point in the #!.

Comment: It doesn't work either. Why is the exclamation point needed?

Comment: Can you try this??<div class="onepost col-xs-4 box" ng-repeat="post in collatedPostList track by $index">
                 <div class="inner">
                <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">{{post.title}}</a>
                <p>{{post.body | limitTo: 60}}{{post.body.length < 20 ? '' : '...'}}</p>
            </div>

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Maybe I have to change something in the route provider?

Comment: Can you just remove and try "/" <a href="#posts/{{post.indexOf(post)}}">{{post.title}}</a>, Also can u share route configurations?

Comment: route config is in my JS, I shared it in my question

Comment: <a href="#posts/{{post.indexOf(post)}}">{{post.title}}</a> -  this opens a page, but a blank one.

Comment: Add one more configiuration.when('/posts/:postID', {
        templateUrl: 'posts.htm',
        controller: 'PostController'
    })

Comment: change `<a href="#/posts/{{post.id}}">` to `<a href="{{'#/posts/'+post.id}}">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do following changes::

Codepen  :http://codepen.io/ruhul/pen/mAJLEo

1) Remove "/" from your href and use post.id (I believe on a click of link, you will be doing some of the database calls based on postID and will render it to UI ).

```
<div class="onepost col-xs-4 box" ng-repeat="post in collatedPostList track by $index"> <div class="inner"> <a href="#/posts/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a> <p>{{post.body | limitTo: 60}}{{post.body.length < 20 ? '' : '...'}}</p> </div>
```

2) As you are passing parameter add your routing configuration as below::
   You can later use this parameter in controller using $routeParams.

```
.when('/posts/:postId', { templateUrl: 'posts.htm', controller: 'PostController' })
```

3) Change your controller to this::

```
myApp.controller('PostController', function($scope,$routeParams,$http) {
  console.log($routeParams.postId)
   $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"+$routeParams.postId
    }).then(function(response) {$scope.post=response.data});
});
```

Comment: that solution gives a blank page

Comment: btw, where is "postID" from?

Comment: {{post.id}} part form your url will be mapped to postID, e.i if your url is #/posts/1 , postID=1. In controller  $routeParams.postID will give you 1.

Comment: http://codepen.io/summerfreeze/pen/EgjEKV I think I did everything like you said, but it still doesn't work

Comment: See my edited answer....follow all three steps and it should work, It is working for me.

Comment: ok, I rushed. It does work, but only for some posts and it's not showing the one that should be

Comment: check you dont have #/posts/{{$index}}, rather you shoud have #/posts/{{post.id}}

Comment: some of the post show nothing, and some the first or the second post

Comment: see my code pen http://codepen.io/ruhul/pen/mAJLEo it is working fine...only #/posts/{{$index}} can cause problem..double check..clear the browser and retest it.

Comment: Did it work, kindly accept the answer if it worked ?